# Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found?

Tags: flutter, dart

hello community hope y'all doing fine,

so i just started learning flutter by following this dude  [tuto](https://youtu.be/x0uinJvhNxI)  now i'm a week stack in this problem `Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.`  in the line 28

> () => answerquestions( answer['score']) ,

while passing answer['score'] as an argumet in the answerquestion function

yes hoover it's a quiz game demo flutter application

code :

main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './questions.dart';
import './Answer.dart';
import './quiz.dart';

//void main (){
//runApp(MyApp());
//}
void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': 'what is your favorite color ?',
      'answer': [
        {'text': 'black', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'red', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Green', 'score': 8},
        {'text': 'White', 'score': 1}
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'what \'s your favorite pet  ?',
      'answer': [
        {'text': 'Cat', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Snake', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Elephant', 'score': 8},
        {'text': 'Lion', 'score': 4}
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'what \'s your favorite instractor  ?',
      'answer': [
        {'text': 'youtoub', 'score': 9},
        {'text': 'Nabile', 'score': 8},
        {'text': 'Nadhem', 'score': 7},
        {'text': 'jiji', 'score': 10}
      ],
    },
  ];
  var _questionindex = 0;
  var _totaleScore = 0;

  void _answerquestions(int score) {
    // if (_questionindex < _questions.length) {}
    _totaleScore += score;
    setState(() {
      _questionindex++;
    });
    print(_questionindex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('my first app'),
        ),
        body: _questionindex < _questions.length
            ? Quiz(
                questions: _questions,
                questionindex: _questionindex,
                answerquestions: _answerquestions,
              )
            : Center(
                child: Text(' you did it bro '),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answers.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() selectHandler;
  final String answerText;

  Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.blue,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        child: Text(answerText),
        onPressed: selectHandler,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

questions.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Questions extends StatelessWidget {
 final String questionsText;

  const Questions(this.questionsText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Text(
        questionsText,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Quiz.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './questions.dart';
import './Answer.dart';

class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionindex;

  final  Function() answerquestions;

  Quiz(
      {required this.questions,
      required this.questionindex,
      required this.answerquestions});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Questions(
          questions[questionindex]['questionText'] as String,
        ),
        ...(questions[questionindex]['answer'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
          //  int xanswer = answer['score'] as int ;
          return Answer(
              () => answerquestions( answer['score']) ,
              answer['text'] as String);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

i tried adding :

> score : answer['score']

evenn using a local variable didn't help  like :

> int xanswer = answer['score'] as int ;

the error is something about dart fundamental that i couldn't handle

thank you for your attention happy coding

Comment: () => answerquestions( answer['score'])  what's answer here?

Answer (score 1):

In the class Quiz, your argument

```
final  Function() answerquestions;
```

doesn't accept parameters (the () of Function() is empty).
This sould be

```
final  Function(int) answerquestions;
```

Comment: thank you so much it solved the issues by adding "as int" the parameters tho
thank you so much a relay appreciate .